# Bidimensional array to single array

Tags: java

Hi people of the community, i have this problem, i'm trying to pass a bidimensional  array  to a simple array(more explicit: `String[][] to String[]`), and always is the same. it marks me null in the first position of the array when i convert the String[][] to String[] i've try everything i know but nothing works to erase the null space into the array. someone can help me? here is the code:

```
public class main {

    public main(){

        String[][] str={
                {"uno","dos","tres"},
                {"unos","dose","trese"},
                {"uno","dos","tres"},

        };

        String[] str2=new String[3] ;

        for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
                str2[i]+=str[i][j];

            }
        }


        for(int i=0;i<3;i++){

                System.out.print(str2[i]);
                System.out.print("\n");
            }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new main();

    }
```

and this is the result i got:

```
nullunodostres

nullunosdosetrese

nullunodostres
```

now you can see, it turns the `String[][]` into `String[]`, but always keep the `null` at first position. and if i try to start the loop `i=1` instead of `i=0,` just disappear the first position of the values but the null continues.
 Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're not initializing the values inside `str2` to anything, and so they all have the value `null`. When you use string contatenation (`+`), the value `null` gets converted to the string `"null"` and put in front of your first element's value. Try this:

```
String[] str2 = new String[3];
Arrays.fill(str2, "");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i didn't know the "fill" method

Answer (score 0):

Its because initially every element in a array of string is implicitly initialized to null

You have to explicitly assign it in order to get rid of null

for example str2[0]="";